# How to force default css of a element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a standard checkbox template which works on a simple html page :

But, on my webpage due to interference from other css styling, it does not render as checkboxes.

Only the text is visible and no checkbox icon. Am unable to force the checkbox behaviour here. Its probably because in my css file, I have styling for labels and input checked. But, I want to force the default behaviour for this tag.

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    html, body {
      height: 120vh;
    }
    
    body {
      font: 14px/1 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      color: #555;
      background: #eee;
    }
    
    h1 {
      padding: 20px 0;
      font-weight: 100;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    p {
      margin: 0 0 20px;
      line-height: 1.5;
    }
    
    main {
      min-width: 520px;
      /*max-width: 800px;*/
      padding: 50px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background: #fff;
    }
    
    section {
      display: none;
      padding: 20px 0 0;
      border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    
    input {
      display: none;
    }
    
    label {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0 0 -1px;
      padding: 15px 25px;
      font-weight: 600;
      text-align: center;
      color: #bbb;
      border: 1px solid transparent;
    }
    
    label:before {
      font-family: fontawesome;
      font-weight: normal;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
    
    label[for*='1']:before { content: '\f1cb'; }
    label[for*='2']:before { content: '\f17d'; }
    label[for*='3']:before { content: '\f16b'; }
    label[for*='4']:before { content: '\f1a9'; }
    
    label:hover {
      color: #888;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    input:checked + label {
      color: #555;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      border-top: 2px solid orange;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    }
    
    #tab1:checked ~ #content1,
    #tab2:checked ~ #content4,
    #tab3:checked ~ #content2,
    #tab4:checked ~ #content3 {
      display: block;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
      label {
        font-size: 0;
      }
      label:before {
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 18px;
      }
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      label {
        padding: 15px;
      }
    }
    
    /*Table */
    .table-wrapper {
     -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
     overflow-x: auto;
    }
    
    table {
     margin: 0 0 2rem 0;
     width: 100%;
    }
    
     table tbody tr {
      border: solid 1px;
      border-left: 0;
      border-right: 0;
     }
    
     table td {
      padding: 0.75rem 0.75rem;
     }
    
     table th {
      font-size: 0.9rem;
      font-weight: 700;
      padding: 0 0.75rem 0.75rem 0.75rem;
      text-align: left;
     }
    
     table thead {
      border-bottom: solid 2px;
     }
    
     table tfoot {
      border-top: solid 2px;
     }
    
     table.alt {
      border-collapse: separate;
     }
    
      table.alt tbody tr td {
       border: solid 1px;
       border-left-width: 0;
       border-top-width: 0;
      }
    
       table.alt tbody tr td:first-child {
        border-left-width: 1px;
       }
    
      table.alt tbody tr:first-child td {
       border-top-width: 1px;
      }
    
      table.alt thead {
       border-bottom: 0;
      }
    
      table.alt tfoot {
       border-top: 0;
      }
    
    table tbody tr {
     border-color: rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.25);
    }
    
     table tbody tr:nth-child(2n + 1) {
      background-color: rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.075);
     }
    
    table th {
     color: #555;
    }
    
    table thead {
     border-bottom-color: rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.25);
    }
    
    table tfoot {
     border-top-color: rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.25);
    }
    
    table.alt tbody tr td {
     border-color: rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.25);
    }
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have a car<br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Please suggest. 
Also attaching the css file in case that helps :

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overwrite (or remove if possible) the

```
input {
    display: none;
}
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 120vh;
}

body {
  font: 14px/1 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #555;
  background: #eee;
}

h1 {
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

main {
  min-width: 520px;
  /*max-width: 800px;*/
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
}

section {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 -1px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  color: #bbb;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

label:before {
  font-family: fontawesome;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

label[for*='1']:before { content: '\f1cb'; }
label[for*='2']:before { content: '\f17d'; }
label[for*='3']:before { content: '\f16b'; }
label[for*='4']:before { content: '\f1a9'; }

label:hover {
  color: #888;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:checked + label {
  color: #555;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 2px solid orange;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

#tab1:checked ~ #content1,
#tab2:checked ~ #content4,
#tab3:checked ~ #content2,
#tab4:checked ~ #content3 {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  label {
    font-size: 0;
  }
  label:before {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  label {
    padding: 15px;
  }
}

/*Table */
.table-wrapper {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

table {
    margin: 0 0 2rem 0;
    width: 100%;
}

    table tbody tr {
        border: solid 1px;
        border-left: 0;
        border-right: 0;
    }

    table td {
        padding: 0.75rem 0.75rem;
    }

    table th {
        font-size: 0.9rem;
        font-weight: 700;
        padding: 0 0.75rem 0.75rem 0.75rem;
        text-align: left;
    }

    table thead {
        border-bottom: solid 2px;
    }

    table tfoot {
        border-top: solid 2px;
    }

    table.alt {
        border-collapse: separate;
    }

        table.alt tbody tr td {
            border: solid 1px;
            border-left-width: 0;
            border-top-width: 0;
        }

            table.alt tbody tr td:first-child {
                border-left-width: 1px;
            }

        table.alt tbody tr:first-child td {
            border-top-width: 1px;
        }

        table.alt thead {
            border-bottom: 0;
        }

        table.alt tfoot {
            border-top: 0;
        }

table tbody tr {
    border-color: rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.25);
}

    table tbody tr:nth-child(2n + 1) {
        background-color: rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.075);
    }

table th {
    color: #555;
}

table thead {
    border-bottom-color: rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.25);
}

table tfoot {
    border-top-color: rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.25);
}

table.alt tbody tr td {
    border-color: rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.25);
}

/* ADD THIS */

input {
  display: block!important;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have a car<br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove your `display: none` from CSS for `input`

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 120vh;
}

body {
  font: 14px/1 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #555;
  background: #eee;
}

h1 {
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

main {
  min-width: 520px;
  /*max-width: 800px;*/
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
}

section {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}



label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 -1px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  color: #bbb;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

label:before {
  font-family: fontawesome;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

label[for*='1']:before { content: '\f1cb'; }
label[for*='2']:before { content: '\f17d'; }
label[for*='3']:before { content: '\f16b'; }
label[for*='4']:before { content: '\f1a9'; }

label:hover {
  color: #888;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:checked + label {
  color: #555;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 2px solid orange;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

#tab1:checked ~ #content1,
#tab2:checked ~ #content4,
#tab3:checked ~ #content2,
#tab4:checked ~ #content3 {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  label {
    font-size: 0;
  }
  label:before {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  label {
    padding: 15px;
  }
}

/*Table */
.table-wrapper {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

table {
    margin: 0 0 2rem 0;
    width: 100%;
}

    table tbody tr {
        border: solid 1px;
        border-left: 0;
        border-right: 0;
    }

    table td {
        padding: 0.75rem 0.75rem;
    }

    table th {
        font-size: 0.9rem;
        font-weight: 700;
        padding: 0 0.75rem 0.75rem 0.75rem;
        text-align: left;
    }

    table thead {
        border-bottom: solid 2px;
    }

    table tfoot {
        border-top: solid 2px;
    }

    table.alt {
        border-collapse: separate;
    }

        table.alt tbody tr td {
            border: solid 1px;
            border-left-width: 0;
            border-top-width: 0;
        }

            table.alt tbody tr td:first-child {
                border-left-width: 1px;
            }

        table.alt tbody tr:first-child td {
            border-top-width: 1px;
        }

        table.alt thead {
            border-bottom: 0;
        }

        table.alt tfoot {
            border-top: 0;
        }

table tbody tr {
    border-color: rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.25);
}

    table tbody tr:nth-child(2n + 1) {
        background-color: rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.075);
    }

table th {
    color: #555;
}

table thead {
    border-bottom-color: rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.25);
}

table tfoot {
    border-top-color: rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.25);
}

table.alt tbody tr td {
    border-color: rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<form>
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have a car<br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```